# is it possible to view all public posts and comments by userId

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Looking over a 2 days and couldn' get an answer, is it possible to view all public posts comments by fbid using FB api search?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get any public posts or comments for specific fbid, you only can search ALL the public posts on facebook via Graph API : [Searching Facebook all public posts only for posts with links using Graph API or FQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290961/searching-facebook-all-public-posts-only-for-posts-with-links-using-graph-api-or?rq=1)