# Automatically find public posts and comments on Facebook and unlike/remove them?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook for many years, and I've liked and commented a lot of friends posts (status, photos, etc). The problem is that I didn't pay attention to that these posts were "public" or "for friends only". As a result, a person who is not a friends of mine can now see all these contents using a request of Graph Search like:

```
Photos liked by USERNAME
Posts liked by USERNAME
Posts commented on by USERNAME
...
```

Of course I could remove likes and comments one by one from the Activity log, but it would take several months... I could also use the Toolkit for Facebook available on Chrome, but unfortunately it only proposes to remove ALL likes or comments, of any kind, whereas I want to do it only for public ones.

**Edit**: This Chrome pluggin is actually a fake, don't use it!

Is there a way to do it with Graph API?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834799/is-it-possible-to-view-all-public-posts-and-comments-by-userid) seems to mention there isn't, but I'm not sure. I found this [post](http://nileshzemase.blogspot.fr/2013/12/likeunlike-facebook-post-or-comment.html) for instance.

**Edit**: @CBroe confirms "Facebook has recently removed the ability to (un-)like objects in the name of the user" so I guess the latter link is obsolete?

Admitting we've retrieved the posts or comments ID, for instance by parsing the html response of the Graph Search result, then:

**Is there another way to launch a request to FB which unlikes or removes posts/comments?**

What do you think about it?
Thanks!

Comment: Facebook has recently removed the ability to (un-)like objects in the name of the user.

Comment: Another idea please?